# Is there a way to inspect the xhr request details when there's an ajax error in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

Is there anyway I can get the request details when there's an ajax error. The callback functions passed into $.ajax() are invoked with an xhr object but it doesn't seem to contain the information I need like the url requested or the http method, POST, GET etc.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Comment: Thanks man. that's exactly what I needed. Don't know why they just don't pass the request object into the error callbacks anyway.

Comment: Hmm, they should. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ -> `error(*jqXHR*, textStatus, errorThrown)`

Comment: the jqXHR param doesn't contain the original request details. Not that I can see anyway. $.ajaxError is has a ajaxSettings param which contains detials of the original request.

Answer (score 0):

Most script debuggers log XHR requests/responses. Chrome Dev Tools does it in the Network tab (Dev tools must be open prior to the request being made). Firebug does it in the Net tab. It contains all information about the request.

Comment: I want to inspect the request in my code and broadcast a message based on the http method etc. I know I can inspect it using a browser.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon the accepted answer, I use the following script to alert my users and myself that an AJAX error has occurred:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    if (exception == 'abort') {return false;}
    if (exception === '') {exception = 'user aborted process';}
    alert('An AJAX error [' + exception + '] occurred in script: ' + settings.url + '<br \><br \>Please report this to the development team!');
    console.log(event, jqxhr, settings, exception);
});
```